# Connecting React Native Socket.io-client with Python Server

Tags: javascript, python, react-native, websocket, socket.io

I'm trying to connect a React Native client to the open Python server

The problem is that I read several resolutions on how to start a connection with the socket.io-client API, but nothing solves it.

It just doesn't connect. I will post the server and the client, and I have changed them several times.

Edit*1: The server side works, I tested it, using socket.io and python socket. But the client being React does not work

```
import React,{useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Pressable, Button } from 'react-native';
import socketIO from "socket.io-client";



export default class App extends React.Component {


  constructor(props){
    super(props)

    this.state = {
      string:"null",
      chatMessage:"null",
      chatMessages:[]
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.socket = socketIO('192.168.0.107:15156')
    this.socket.connect(); 
    this.socket.on('connect', () => { 
      console.log('connected to socket server'); 
    }); 
  }

  submitChatMessage(message) {
    console.log(this.socket)
    this.socket.emit('chat message', message);
    this.setState({chatMessage: ''});
  }



  render() {

    return (

      <View style={{flex: 1,backgroundColor:'#000000', alignItems:'center', justifyContent:'center'}}>
  
          <Button title="Start" onPress={()=>{this.submitChatMessage('connected')}}></Button>
       

        </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Server

```
import socket

host = "192.168.0.107"              
port = 15156            
tcp = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
orig = (host, port)

tcp.bind(orig)
tcp.listen(1)

while True:
        con, cliente = tcp.accept()
        print ('Connected', cliente)
        while True:
                msg = con.recv(1024)
                if not msg: break
                print (cliente, msg)
        print ('exiting', cliente)
        con.close()
```

Edit*2: I tried to catch any error generated when connecting to the server, and simply created the socket object, without connecting to the server, not generating an error. How is this possible. There is no connection in the image and the object is created

```
  componentDidMount() {
    this.connectSocket()
  }

  connectSocket() {
    try {
      console.log("Connecting to the server...")
      this.socket = io('http://192.168.0.107:15156',{autoConnect:false})
      this.socket.connect()
      console.log("Sucess");
    }
    catch (err){
      console.log(err)
    }
  }
```

[image]

Edit*3
I was able to detect an error when using this,

```
this.socket.on("connect_error", (err) => {
        console.log(err)
      })
```

// ***[Error: xhr poll error]*** //Looping

The point is, it could have been better not to have found it.
Any way forward?

Comment: I think you need to use socket.io on the server too. [socket.io](https://python-socketio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/server.html#creating-a-server-instance)

Comment: I created to test a server with socket.io in python and without success

Comment: I looked here quickly, and removing the possibility of being a problem with the version of the socket.io used, what I see that may be wrong is the server address, try to put it: ```this.socket = socketIO('http://192.168.0.107:15156')``` instead of ```192.168.0.107: 15156```

Comment: This is a variation that I also tested. I used the latest version of socket.io and 2.1.1

Comment: I just forgot to connect the android to the network, lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just forgot to connect the android on the network, third day for that